# Returning an rvalue versus returning a local object by value

Tags: c++

In this case we return the rvalue immediately:

```
class boVector() {};

boVector createBoVector() {
  return boVector();
}

void main() {
  boVector reusable = createBoVector();
}
```

Where as in this case we create a local variable then return it by value:

```
class boVector() {};

boVector createBoVector() {
  boVector bv;
  return bv;
}

void main() {
  boVector reusable = createBoVector();
}
```

What are the **total number of copies** in each case?  Is there an extra copy in the former?

Comment: I think you can try this in some compiler with and without optimizations. With optimizations, both should have the same count i.e. 0 (RVO for case 1 and NRVO for case 2)

Comment: @legends2k What is RVO and NRVO?

Comment: @jakeliquorblues: [Return Value Optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both cases you create a local variable in `createBoVector()`. `reusable` is then copy-constructed from that local object, before said local goes out of scope and is destroyed.

The only difference is that one time you make the local variable explicit (`boVector bv`), one time you don't. All that matters here is the return type of `boVector`.

It may be that compilers can optimize your simple example to avoid the copy, e.g. by inlining `createBoVector()`, but you can't really influence that or rely on that. And, unless your objects are prohibitively expensive to copy (unlikely), you shouldn't worry about it either.

Answer (score 0):

> What are the total number of copies in each case?

If you implement the *copy constructor* (and *copy assignment* operator) in your class, you can count the copies for yourself.:

```
int copies = 0;

class boVector()
{
public:
    boVector(const boVector&) { ++copies; }
    boVector& operator=(const boVector &) { ++copies; return *this; }
};

void main() {
  boVector reusable = createBoVector();
  cout << "copies: << copies << endl;
}
```